# SQL Group by column and column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sql-query-store

I have a hiring table like below:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| slot_id  |  hired_days |  qty  |  amt  |  return   |
-----------|-------------|-------|-------|-----------|
|    1     |     30      |   5   |  100  |     0     |
|    1     |     30      |  15   |  300  |     0     |
|    1     |     30      |  12   |  170  |     1     |
|    1     |     25      |  13   |  180  |     0     |
|    1     |     30      |   4   |  180  |     1     |
|    2     |     30      |  15   |  300  |     0     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the result to be grouped by slot_id and hired_days but the grouping should be done only for the return value of 0 rows. The result table needs to display all grouped rows and return 1 data. Is there any way to do this with SQL?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| slot_id  |  hired_days |   qty  |  amt  |  return   |
|----------|-------------|--------|-------|-----------|
|   1      |     30      |   20   |  400  |     0     |
|   1      |     25      |   13   |  180  |     0     |
|   1      |     30      |   12   |  170  |     1     |
|   1      |     30      |    4   |  180  |     1     |
|   2      |     30      |   15   |  300  |     0     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` operation

```
SELECT slot_id,hired_days,sum(qty),sum(amt),return FROM hiring
WHERE return=0 GROUP BY slot_id,hired_days 
UNION ALL 
SELECT slot_id,hired_days,qty,amt,return FROM hiring WHERE return =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query....

```
select slot_id, hired_days, sum(qty), sum(amt), return from hiring where return = 0 group by slot_id, hired_days, return union select slot_id, hired_days, qty, amt, return from hiring where return = 1
```